# NSArray SIGABRT

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, sigabrt, nsindexpath

```
NSString* year = [self.years objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

//get algorithms for that year
NSArray* algorithmSection = [self.algorithmNames objectForKey:year];

NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

//get specific algorithm based on that row
cell.textLabel.text = [algorithmSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

For whatever reason, when I compile this, I get a SIGABRT error. It happens on the

```
cell.textLabel.text
```

line. Error:

2011-08-29 19:26:21.273 xxxxxxxxxxx[1431:b303]  2 indexes [0, 0]

2011-08-29 19:26:21.274 xxxxxxxxxxxxx[1431:b303] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ba2370

2011-08-29 19:26:21.277 xxxxxxxxx[1431:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ba2370'
terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `algorithmSection` variable, which your code expects to be an `NSArray`, is actually an `NSDictionary`, which does not respond to the selector `-objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: Well how can I fix that, while keeping the same transfer of information?

Comment: I can't tell you without knowing more about how you're storing your data.  Presumably, you'd replace the call to `-objectAtIndex:` to `-objectForKey:` with an appropriate key to access the text you want to set on the cell's `textLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

As lemnar and mjisawai said, you are actually dealing with an NSDictionary.

The way to fix this depends on the context of your app. 
If you happen to receive either, NSArrays or NSDictionary objects then you may determine this by texting the object's class.

i.e.

```
if ([algorithmSection isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
  ...
} else if ([algorithmSection isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Alright, I actually just needed to change some of the values in the plist. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Well, yes of course. It is your choice to amend the data feed, your plist in this case, or the processing of this data :)

Answer (score 0):

Could the object at key "year" in your algorithmSections dictionary be a dictionary instead of an array? That's what it looks like is happening here.